# DGCharts EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x12a113e30)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, charts, apple-m1

Previously this [Repository](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) was imported as Charts, but after their library updates, it was changed to DGCharts. After I change the pod file, it installed successfully but the app getting crashed while accessing the charts. previously it was working properly. The only change was the pod name (Charts -> DGCharts).

[image]

[image]

Note that I'm using M1 Macbook.

Also, I tried to import the library as

pod 'DGCharts' as well. but the result was the same.

Comment: Is there an error message in Console when it crashes?

Comment: There is no any error console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. It turned out that the module name of the PieChartView in my Storyboard still was the old library name. Just make sure the PieChartView's Module is set to "DGCharts".

Images: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQYcc.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6dDm.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Super @Moritz! you saved my day